# What are the major drawbacks of having a domain that contains characters with accents?

Tags: dns, hosting, special-characters

I am considering getting a domain that contains an accented character (it contains an á). However, I noticed that only some companies offer them. Is there a general problem with those domains or will I have certain disadvantages when using one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DNS protocol only supports ASCII. Domains with accented characters in them are encoded to ASCII using [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). That means that your domain `éxàmplê.com` is actually `xn--xmpl-0na6cm.com`.

It is a virtual certainty that there is lots of software out there that doesn't support [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDN). It's up to you to test in your environment and decide whether the advantages of a rich character set in your domain name is worth the trouble.

Here are just a few things to check, just off the top of my head.

- Does your web browser support IDNs? (probably it does).
- Do all the web browsers used by your web site's visitors support them?
- Does your email server software support them?
- Does your mail user agent support them (i.e. does it work when you configure an email account with email address `myself@éxàmplê.com`)?
- Do the mail servers and mail user agent software used by all your email correspondents support IDNs?
- Does your SSH client accept IDNs (`ssh myserver.éxàmplê.com`)?
- Does your syslog server support them? Your database client? Your load balancer (if you use names, not IP addresses)?
- Do they work in `/etc/hosts`?
- Can your DHCP clients and servers handle accented characters in the DNS domain?
- etc...
- *so many more*!

The answer to lots of those is probably no. In that case you can always configure the particular software in question with the raw punycoded form of the domain, but do you really want to write `xn--xmpl-0na6cm.com` in config files and look at that string in server logs?

Comment: Well, I would like to use such a domain for a blog hosted on github. Do you think that that would work?

Comment: I think if it's web (HTTP & HTTPS) only you are relatively safe, but I have no experience so I don't know. Will your git client need to support pushing to a remote repository with an accent in its URL? Possible, but I have my doubts! Adding email is another risk. Adding a server whose FQDN is under that domain is a bigger risk. Using it on an internal network (DHCP domain, LDAP domain, NFS server domain name, etc...) is an even bigger risk. In general: the fewer services you host using the domain name, the better your chances of success are!

Comment: Thanks, I think I will give it a try and see if it works. If not, I can still switch to a usual domain