# What are the major drawbacks of having a domain that contains characters with accents as of 2020?

Tags: dns, hosting, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

I am wondering what are the drawbacks of using accents (like French accents) in a domain name.

I have read a similar question/answers from 2013 at [What are the major drawbacks of having a domain that contains characters with accents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976405/what-are-the-major-drawbacks-of-having-a-domain-that-contains-characters-with-ac) which clearly explains that the DNS protocol only supports ASCII, and accented characters are just "sugar" that the browser performs.

I actually have two questions:

1. What are the drawbacks when you plan on using it for a simple website? (you basically want the url to "sound like French", in our case)

   Of course, as stated in 2013, links toward accented urls might not be displayed as links but as text instead, but that's boring/trivial. Are there other very strong reasons not to use accents?
2. What are the drawbacks when you plan on using it for more just a simple website?

   (like a company/brand name, etc.) This is basically what
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981455/2391795 answers, but it's 7
   years old and it might have changed since then.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programmming. But some ideas: you may not pass the radio test, if someone else has the non accentued version it may create confusion, voluntarily or not (some registries block variants, some others not), and many people and interfaces are not yet up to date and will refuse domain names with non ascii characters (the `xn--` version would work then, but this is ugly in UI). Browsers will not have problems with it, per se.

Comment: Also, IDNs are a part of the problem of "Universal Acceptance". This resource (from ICANN) can give you details: https://uasg.tech/

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! I didn't know there was such a desire to make the web accept all languages. It's true that it's unfair it only handles ascii chars so far. Especially for people with a completely different alphabet.

Comment: "Inclusiveness" is indeed a big trend lately and of course has technical consequences. Allowing people to use their own local native characters, no matter which ones, in all their life online is kind of a goal... maybe coming too late because if you study IDNs numbers, you will see there are not hugely used in fact and their % does not really increase over time. IDN TLDs may not be very successful either. Maybe it is too complicated too late (when you said to people: do not use accents because of technical constraints, they keep the idea even if later you can use them).

Comment: Yup, I still see many French folks who believe they shouldn't use uppercased accented letters (e.g: 'É È, À, Ù') because that wasn't technically possible during their time and they never got up-to-date with new rules. Especially true with people 40+yo.